# Print NSMutableArray to email body

Tags: ios, arrays, nsmutablearray

I am new to iOS development and i am working on my first app. I have a piece of code that is suppose to add data from my NSMutableArray to the body of an email when i share it. I ran into an issue where the array description just prints out the address of the data and not the actual data. I understand that this is an expected behavior, how can i display contents of the array in the email body?

Here is the code I wrote:

```
- (void)displayMailComposerSheet
{

    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Attendance"]; 

    NSString *data = [self.attendItems description];

    [picker setMessageBody:data isHTML:NO];

    [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: cant find the array here. if you have an array,then loop through it, append or even you can use `componentsJoinedByString:` method to form a string from array.

Comment: @Anoop Vaidya: "self.attendItems" seems to be the array. Why not post it as an answer? Seems perfectly fine with me.

Comment: @SebastianWramba: as you say, I do. Answer posted.

Answer (score 6):

Instead of

```
NSString *data = [self.attendItems description];
```

Use something like:

```
NSString *data = [self.attendItems componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
```

All the values in the array will be joined by a comma (,).